# How to get border width of an element in IE7 with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I'm attempting to get the width of an element's border with `$('#foo').css('border-width-bottom')`, but in IE7 this returns `medium` rather than an number, or even a string with a number in it (ie 7px).

Is there a way to get the width, in pixels, of an element's border in IE7?  I know I can cheat and map the strings to their pixel equivalents, but is there a cleaner way to do it?

Update: I know that if you are explicitly setting the border in pixels, it will return the proper value, but what if it is set to 'medium'?  I want the width in pixels, not the border-width property value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`border-bottom-width` works just fine in IE7, here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2P7cn/

```
$(function(){
   alert($("#test").css("border-bottom-width")); 
});
```

Edit: The "medium/thick/thin" values are browser dependent. With some trickery (outerHeight-height-padding), you could figure out the border height sum and subtract the known one (or divide by 2 if they're both medium).

Comment: Sorry, I should update my question.  If you explicitly set it, then it works, but what if you set it to 'medium'.  FF will return a px amount, whereas IE7 will stay with 'medium'.  +1 for looking into it though.

Comment: I see what you mean. The "medium/thick/thin" values are browser dependent. With some trickery (outerHeight-height-padding), you could figure out the border height sum and subtract the known one (or divide by 2 if they're both medium). Hope that helps.

Comment: Why not just set it to a pixel height all the time?  That way you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: I don't have access to the css and shouldn't change it through jquery, really.